# What do "gives a damn" and "sucker of that slime" mean in these song lyrics?

Tags: word-meaning

> Oh who said life was easy
>   who said life was fair
>   who said nobody **gives a damn** and nobody even cares
>   The way you’re acting now like you left that all behind
>   You've given up, you've given in
>   Another **sucker of that slime**

My intuition is that the word "damn" here has to do with "condemn" or "criticizing".

I have drawn a blank trying to define what the expression "sucker of slime" means here.

Complete lyrics [here](http://www.amymacdonald.co.uk/gb/lyrics/poison_prince/).

Comment: Sucker of slime: Ms. McDonald characterizes the Poison Prince, the artist who has abandoned his art to live in drugs and his emotional problems, as a 'bottom feeder' a fish that roots for its food in the slime at the bottom of a river.

Answer (score 1):

Someone who "doesn't give a damn" doesn't care at all about something. I believe it comes from the use of the word "damn" as a mild swearword; someone who isn't even bothered enough by something (usually something generally considered important) to express their concern with even a mild swearword "doesn't give (utter) a damn".

"Sucker of that slime" is not a common English idiom, so I wouldn't worry about it too much. I'll cede to StoneyB's comment about its actual meaning.

Answer (score 0):

According to [princeton wordnet](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=give%20a%20damn) "to give a damn" means

> show no concern or interest; 
>   and always used in the negative.

Comment: Technically, it would mean "show concern or interest" if it weren't used in the negative.

Comment: Well, there said it always used in the negative. I never seen a positive form.

Comment: I think I have, but only in humorous contexts that also use words like "gruntled" and "sheveled".

Comment: Why should I give a damn?

Comment: @AlanThird: I'd tell you if I gave a damn.

Comment: To give or not give a damn, that is the question.

Comment: "If anybody gave a damn"